# Reading date from excel file for different locations

Tags: java, apache, date, apache-poi, locale

I am reading an Excel file in Java using Apache POI.

There are columns which are Date formatted and the format is MM/DD/YYYY

When I read the file in India, it reads the date properly.

e.g. 04/07/2015 is read as 07-Apr-2015
e.g. 11/30/2014 is read as 30-Nov-2015

This is fine.

But, when the same code is run in US, it behaves odd.

e.g. 04/07/2015 is read as 04-Jul-2015
e.g. 11/30/2014 fails saying 30 is not valid month.

When I open the excel file in MS Excel both in US and India, visibility wise they are same. i.e. in excel it shows as MM/DD/YYYY. But thru code its reading incorrectly in US.

My code is simple:

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
    data.append(cell);
```

Something is done by POI as per the location. Can someone suggest how to handle this situation.

Comment: What happens if you [try using DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) (as per POI documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`cell1.getDateCellValue()` worked correctly):

```
//get your cell value

Cell cell1 = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0); 
System.out.println(cell1.getDateCellValue());
```

OR

Try using the SimpleDateFormat class:

```
//using Apache POI get the date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
Date date = sdf.parse("your date");
String formattedDate=sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Another method to get timezone:

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");
```

Hope this helps!